# What is difference in the design steps between designing an OPAMP vs Miller-OPV?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

I am given a task as:

> Design an operational amplifier (Miller-OPV, 0.35μm) according to the
>   introduced design plan and the given lab technology that meets the
>   following specification:

What is the difference between normal opamp and miller opamp?

Are there any good design steps for Miller-OPV?

Comment: You're going to have to give more information.  There are Miller compensation schemes, nested miller compensation and miller integrators and Miller's theorem for a short list.  OPV seems to be a German term which is not commonly used in english texts so a definition would be handy.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, the German version of Wikipedia shows a circuit diagram for a MOSFET based Miller opamp, whereas the English version does not.

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differenzverst%C3%A4rker

Try running it through Google Translate and you get:

> This simple and much used in the integrated circuit technique called Miller operational amplifier circuit, because the Miller effect compensation for the frequency, that is, to suppress the tendency to oscillate at high frequencies is employed. The total gain at low frequencies is more than 105 and Miller capacitor decreases because of the increasing frequency.

Image:

[image]